# Error Message by DisplayMember

Tags: combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm getting an error using AjaxControlToolKit Combobox and trying to fill the dropdownlist from database.

Combobox1.DisplayMember returns the message 'AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox does not contain a definition for 'DisplayMember' but i found some examples with DisplayMember

AjaxControlToolkit was downloaded over NuGet and Reference is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AjaxControlToolkit ComboBox does not contain DisplayMemeber property. It can be easily checked with the [Ajax Control Toolkit source code](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AjaxControlToolkit/ComboBox/ComboBox.cs) and IntelliSense.

I suppose you messed up with default [WinForms ComboBox control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which in fact has this property.